# PHP doesn't print whole table

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to make a barebones blog in which it prints everything from  a mySQL table but it seems to only print the first row. I have two blocks of PHP code and it's the 2nd.

As you can see in the code, I'm printing the latest row in a separate block first so if you also know how to skip the newest row in the table for the 2nd block that would also be nice.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
include_once"connect.php"; //Inkluderar connect.php filen

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/post-style.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:600,400,300|PT+Sans:400,700|PT+Serif|PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
<?php
    include_once"header.php";

    //Väljer all data från angivna tabellen
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        //Skriver ut data från varje rad
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<div id="newest" style="background-image: url(img/' .$row['img']. ');">';
            echo '<div id="newest-text">';
            echo '<h1 class="title">' . $row['title'] . '</h1>';
            echo '<h3 class="subtitle">' . $row['subtitle'] . '</h3>';
            echo '<a class="fullPost" href="post.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><i>Read More</i></a>';
            echo '</div></div>';
        }
    };
 ?>

<div id="content">
    <?php
    //Väljer all data från angivna tabellen
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        //Skriver ut data från varje rad
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
            echo '<div class="post">';
            echo "<div class='img'><img src=".'img/'.$row['img']." /></div>";
            echo '<h1 class="title">' . $row['title'] . '</h1>';
            echo '<h3 class="subtitle">' . $row['subtitle'] . '</h3>';
            $words = split(" ", $row['content']);
            for ($i = 0; ($i < 50 && $i < count($words)); $i++) {
                echo $words[$i] . " ";
            }
            echo '<br><a class="fullPost" href="post.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><i>Read More</i></a>';
            echo '<div class="line-separator"></div>';
            echo '<p class="tag"> Topic - ' . $row['tag'] . '</p>';
            echo '<p class="date">' . $row['date'] . '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
            }
       };
     ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You're ordering by `id` but not telling whether it's ascending or descending. So change this `SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id` to this `SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id ASC` or `SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: are you using `mysql`, `mysqli` or `pdo` PHP extension?

Comment: @DiddleDot `ORDER BY` defaults to `ASC`.

Comment: @DiddleDot ordering without designation is shorthand for ordering `ASC`ending. It's pretty common and will not cause an error.

Comment: @Nordenheim The functions he's calling only exist in the `mysqli` extension.

Comment: `echo $result->num_rows; ` how many rows does it show you

Comment: BTW, the first block doesn't print the latest row, it prints the earliest row. If you want the latest row, use `ORDER BY id DESC`.

Comment: If you want to skip the row printed by the first block, save `$row['id']` in a variable `$latest_id`, then add `WHERE id != $latest_id` to the second query.

Comment: @meda 4 which is the amount of rows

Comment: @AlexanderBomanSkoug  did you try [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34887263/1880431)

Answer (score 5):

> but it seems to only print the first row

Take a look at your query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**LIMIT 1**

The `LIMIT` clause is used to specify the number of records to return, remove it to get all records.

Comment: But OP is talking about the second block of php code, *...but it seems to only print the first row. I have two blocks of PHP code and it's the 2nd. As you can see in the code, I'm printing the latest row in a separate block first...*

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL has a `LIMIT` clause, meaning that only 1 row is ever returned (the latest row in this case).

If you increase the limit or remove it, your code should display all of those rows.

Comment: The OP is talking about the second code block, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

Since you query the same table 3 times it would be better to query once only:

```
<?php
include_once"connect.php"; //Inkluderar connect.php filen

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

#just for debug
echo 'result->num_rows  = '.$result->num_rows;
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/post-style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:600,400,300|PT+Sans:400,700|PT+Serif|PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
<?php

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //Skriver ut data från varje rad
    if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<div id="newest" style="background-image: url(img/' .$row['img']. ');">';
        echo '<div id="newest-text">';
        echo '<h1 class="title">' . $row['title'] . '</h1>';
        echo '<h3 class="subtitle">' . $row['subtitle'] . '</h3>';
        echo '<a class="fullPost" href="post.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><i>Read More</i></a>';
        echo '</div></div>';
    }
};
?>

<div id="content">
    <?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        //Skriver ut data från varje rad
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo '<div class="post">';
            echo "<div class='img'><img src=".'img/'.$row['img']." /></div>";
            echo '<h1 class="title">' . $row['title'] . '</h1>';
            echo '<h3 class="subtitle">' . $row['subtitle'] . '</h3>';
            $words = split(" ", $row['content']);
            for ($i = 0; ($i < 50 && $i < count($words)); $i++) {
                echo $words[$i] . " ";
            }
            echo '<br><a class="fullPost" href="post.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><i>Read More</i></a>';
            echo '<div class="line-separator"></div>';
            echo '<p class="tag"> Topic - ' . $row['tag'] . '</p>';
            echo '<p class="date">' . $row['date'] . '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

At each call of `fetch_assoc()` the `db` cursor would move  1 record forward until there are no more rows

Comment: Same problem, only printing one thing

Comment: Exactly, it's printing the first block correctly but not the 2nd block

Comment: Did you use this code in my answer exactly? there is no valid reason it would do that